# jQuery: Change <a> to <input> when clicking adjacent <a> in <table>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using jQuery, how can I do the following when clicking the edit icon in the third column:

1. Change the text in the adjacent second column to an input box
2. Change the icon class in the third column to a save button
3. Change the original text in the second column to what was entered into the input box

(Sorry if that's confusing and/or a lot to ask!)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="modal-body">
  <form>
    <table id="modalLinks" class="table table-hover">
      <thead align="left">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col-xs-4">URL</th>
          <th scope="col">Edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody align="left">
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" id="modalLinkName">Link 1</td>
            <td>
              <a id="modalLinkURL">https://www.link1.com</a>
              <input id="modalLinkInput" type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            </td>
            <td>
              <a id="modalEditLink" href="#">icon
                                                <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                                            </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" id="modalLinkName">Link 2</td>
            <td>
              <a id="modalLinkURL">https://www.link2.com</a>
              <input id="modalLinkInput" type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            </td>
            <td>
              <a id="modalEditLink" href="#">icon
                                                <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                                            </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" id="modalLinkName">Link 3</td>
            <td>
              <a id="modalLinkURL">https://www.link3.com</a>
              <input id="modalLinkInput" type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            </td>
            <td>
              <a id="modalEditLink" href="#">icon
                                                <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                                            </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The idea is that you show the code you are trying with and where exactly you bump into an issue. The idea is not that you ask us to write the code for you ;-)

Comment: @trincot I'll edit it to include the jQuery I'm using, but I'll warn you now that it's rather messy... and wrong!

Comment: One thing that you should correct in the HTML: `id` attribute values *must* be unique in HTML. Use class names instead for where you currently have duplicates. Secondly, you have `<th>` opening tags that are closed with `</td>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there are a few issues to fix in your HTML:

- `id` attribute values must be unique in HTML. Use class names instead for where you currently have duplicates.
- you have `<th>` opening tags that are closed with `</td>`

With those changes, you could use this click handler:

```js
$(".modalEditLink").click(function () {
    if ($(this).find(".fa-pen").length) { // edit operation:
        var $a = $(this).closest("tr").find(".modalLinkURL");
        var $inp = $("<input>").addClass("editURL").val($a.text());
        $a.replaceWith($inp);
        $inp.focus();
        $(this).find(".fas").removeClass("fa-pen").addClass("fa-save");
    } else { // save operation:
        var $inp = $(this).closest("tr").find(".editURL");
        var $a = $("<a>").addClass("modalLinkURL").text($inp.val());
        $inp.replaceWith($a);
        $(this).find(".fas").removeClass("fa-save").addClass("fa-pen");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="modalLinks" class="table table-hover">
  <thead align="left">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col-xs-4">URL</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody align="left">
    <tr>
        <td scope="row" class="modalLinkName">Link 1</td>
        <td>
          <a class="modalLinkURL">https://www.link1.com</a>
          <input class="modalLinkInput" type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-sm">
        </td>
        <td>
          <a class="modalEditLink" href="#">icon
                                            <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                                        </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row" class="modalLinkName">Link 2</td>
        <td>
          <a class="modalLinkURL">https://www.link2.com</a>
          <input class="modalLinkInput" type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-sm">
        </td>
        <td>
          <a class="modalEditLink" href="#">icon
                                            <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                                        </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row" class="modalLinkName">Link 3</td>
        <td>
          <a class="modalLinkURL">https://www.link3.com</a>
          <input class="modalLinkInput" type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-sm">
        </td>
        <td>
          <a class="modalEditLink" href="#">icon
                                            <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                                        </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```